# I am dual booting windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04.3 currently. Can I use a separate new partition for both windows and ubuntu to store personal files?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04, home-directory, windows-11

I'm dual booting windows 11 and ubuntu is there anyway that I can keep my personal files in the same but a separate partition?

- Windows 11 is installed in C: .                                (NTFS)
- I used to keep my personal files in E: , a separate partition. (NTFS)
- Ubuntu is installed in a new partition.                         (Ext 4)
- The /home mount point is set to a new partition.
  (Ext 4)

Is there a way to make E: and /home the same partition? (NTFS)

Comment: You cannot make /home as NTFS, it must be a Linux format like default ext4. You can add another partition as NTFS and use from both systems, but Windows fast start up must be off or all NTFS partitions are hibernated and read only from Linux. And bitlocker must be off or it is encrypted.